# Prove that $E(e^{sX^2}) = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-2s}}$

Tags: normal-distribution, expectation

If $X$ is normally distributed with mean $0$ and SD $1$, show that 
$$E(e^{sX^2}) = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-2s}}$$ 
for $s < \dfrac{1}{2}$.

I obtain this from the paper 'Elementary proof of Johnson and Lindenstrauss',under the proof of Lemma $2.2(a)$.

I don't know how to obtain the equality above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to go is to use LOTUS and solve this integral

$$E(e^{sX^2}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2(\frac{1}{2} -s)}dx$$

We will try squaring both sides and solve using polar coordinates.

$$(E(e^{sX^2}))^2 = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-(\frac{1}{2} - s)x^2} e^{-(\frac{1}{2} - s)y^2} dx \> dy  $$

$$ = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_0^{2 \pi} \int_0^{\infty} e^{-(\frac{1}{2} - s)r^2} r \> dr \> d\theta$$

We let $u = (\frac{1}{2} - s)r^2$ and thus $\frac{du}{1 - 2s} = r dr$ .

$$ = \frac{1}{2 \pi (1 - 2s)} \int_0^{2 \pi} \int_0^{\infty} e^{-u} \> du \> d\theta$$

$$= \frac{1}{1- 2s}$$

Thus our initial expected value must equal

$$E(e^{sX^2}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2s}}$$

For reasons having to do with the convergence of the integral we must stipulate that $s < \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Mind to explain what is meant by 'LOTUS'?

Comment: Law of the Unconscious Statistician

Comment: @TnilkImaniq: Is that a quote from a book?

Comment: @copper.hat No it's actually the name of the law.  I believe it's referred as such because of how incredible the idea that you can simply use the old pdf without thinking as if you were unconcious

Comment: @TnilkImaniq: Thanks! I know the rule for many decades but have never heard the term LOTUS :-). Something new every day!

Comment: @copper.hat No problem! Wikipedia seems to use the term so I can attest that I wasn't creative enough to make it up

Comment: It follows directly from the probability density function of the normal distribution with $\mu = 0$ and $\sigma = 1$, the definition of expectation, and the Law of the Unconscious Statistician

Comment: More explicitly, LOTUS says $$E(g(X)) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x) f_X(x) \> dx$$ Here we have $g(X) = e^{sX^2}$ and $f_X(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}$